# Communicating between different threads VB.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, mutex

I've got a console app which can be opened multiple times together. To prevent this from happening I'm using Mutex to detect the new instances and then closing it as below:

```
Private ReadOnly myType As Type = GetType("name of my app")
Dim oMutex As System.Threading.Mutex = New System.Threading.Mutex(False, myType.GUID.ToString()) 

        If oMutex.WaitOne(0, False) = False Then
            Console.WriteLine("Another instance of this app is already running...")            
            oMutex.ReleaseMutex()
            Exit Sub       
        End If
```

My question is how can I pass data from these child instances to the main instance?

Comment: That's not communicating between threads. That's communicating between processes. As such, it would be done in the same way as any other inter-process communication (IPC). That's the subject that you should research.

Comment: Seems to me you're looking at this backwards.  Instead of having the first instance detect the later ones and tell them to close, the more straightforward approach is to have the later ones detect the first one and close themselves (and then you don't even need to worry about communication between them).  This is a common enough pattern that you should be able to find examples with a properly-tailored search.